# Symfony: form_widget passing in a variable as the form field

Tags: forms, symfony

Is it possible to pass a variable to form_widget().

I have some dynamic form fields which are generate inside formBuild.
The only way I can retrieve these fields is if I use form_rest();

Each record could have different fields so i cannot manually add in the fields.

I have passed the field names from the controller into the view. Looped through the field names and trying to create the fields.

See below as an example

```
{% for meta_field in meta_fields %}
  {% set attr_field = 'form.'~ meta_field ~ '.metaValue' %}
    {{ attr_field }}
    {{ form_widget(attr_field) }}
  {% endfor %}
```

error below

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::searchAndRenderBlock() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, string given,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you passed your form as `form` to the template, and that the field names are stored in the `meta_value` key of each `meta_field`, you can get the form's  fields from `meta_fields` with the twig `attr` function like so:

```
{% for meta_field in meta_fields %}
{% set attr_field = attribute(form, meta_field.meta_value) %}
  {{ form_widget(attr_field) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks  `attribute(form, meta_field)` It was attribute not attr.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need!